# Remove quotes from textfield onblur?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the following javascript to remove whitespace from a textfield onblur. Can I include removal of singles and double quotes in the same event?

```
onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$) /g, '');"
```

Comment: Yes you can. There is no restriction on the code or "how much" code you can execute in response to an event. I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn everything you need to know about events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just modify your regex to include quotes and double-quotes.

```
onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)|'|"/g, '');"
```

Comment: This doesn't parse correctly in the onblur attribute (the quotes need to be HTML encoded)

Comment: ahhh.. oops, was working in the console so didn't need to escape quote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'm sure there's a more elegant way but:

```
onblur="this.value=this.value.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$) /g, ''); this.value=this.value.replace(/\'/g, ''); this.value=this.value.replace(/&quot;/g, '');"
```

You have to use " because you are putting it in the onblur attribute.  You should move this code to a .js file and then you can do

```
value.replace(/\"/g, '');
```

instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6FFm/

Comment: Thank you! I tried writing this out several times, but wasn't getting it quite right. Wasted half the day, so this is awesome! :)